# Multiple condition in Case statement-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (SKU INT,    
                    SP FLOAT,   
                    STDC FLOAT,
                    REPC FLOAT,
                    TRUEMAR FLOAT,
                    BRANMAR FLOAT,
                    comment VARCHAR (100)
                   )

INSERT INTO @TAB
    SELECT 40410, 24.34, 23.895, 19.91, 18.2, 1.83, NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 40410, 25.61, 23.895, 19.91, 22.26, 6.7, NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 40410, 24.95, 23.895, 19.91, 20.2, 44.23, NULL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 40410, 25.29, 23.895, 19.91, 21.27, 5.52, NULL
```

WHEN TRUEMAR is less than 0.10 then Comment column should be UR

WHEN TRUEMAR is greater than 0.10 and BARMAR is less than 0.10 then PMR

Or else NA

Unfortunately the below code is returning all as NA.

```
UPDATE @TAB                     
SET Comment = CASE                          
                 WHEN [TRUEMAR] < 0.10 THEN 'UR'                        
                 WHEN [TRUEMAR] > 0.10 and BRANMAR < 0.10 THEN 'PMR'
                 ELSE 'NA'
              END
```

Please share your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: The result looks correct based on the data you have provided.

Comment: You have no [TRUEMAR] < 0.10 **OR** a [TRUEMAR] > 0.10 with a [BRANMAR] < 0.10...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a64c/2 : It's doing what it should...

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your looks fine. Insert some proper data that matches the condition given in the query. Please check this -

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE
(
    SKU INT,    
    SP FLOAT,   
    STDC    FLOAT,
    REPC    FLOAT,
    TRUEMAR FLOAT,
    BRANMAR FLOAT,
    comment VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT @TAB

SELECT 40410,   24.34,  23.895, 19.91,  18.2,   1.83,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 40410,   25.61,  23.895, 19.91,  22.26,  6.7,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 40410,   24.95,  23.895, 19.91,  20.2,   44.23,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 40410,   25.29,  23.895, 19.91,  21.27,  5.52,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 40410,   25.29,  23.895, 19.91,  21.27,  0.08,NULL

select * , CASE                                 
                WHEN [TRUEMAR] > 0.10 and BRANMAR <0.10 THEN 'PMR'  
                WHEN [TRUEMAR] < 0.10 THEN 'UR'                     
                ELSE 'NA'
            END
FROM @TAB
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/*------------------------
OUTPUT
------------------------*/

(5 row(s) affected)
SKU         SP                     STDC                   REPC                   TRUEMAR                BRANMAR                comment       
----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ------------- ----
40410       24.34                  23.895                 19.91                  18.2                   1.83                   NULL          NA
40410       25.61                  23.895                 19.91                  22.26                  6.7                    NULL          NA
40410       24.95                  23.895                 19.91                  20.2                   44.23                  NULL          NA
40410       25.29                  23.895                 19.91                  21.27                  5.52                   NULL          NA
40410       25.29                  23.895                 19.91                  21.27                  0.08                   NULL          PMR

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

your input data like this you able to get that result.

```
INSERT @TAB
SELECT 40410,   24.34,  23.895, 19.91,  0.09,   1.83,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 40410,   25.61,  23.895, 19.91,  0.11,  0.09,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 40410,   24.95,  23.895, 19.91,  20.2,   44.23,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 40410,   25.29,  23.895, 19.91,  21.27,  5.52,NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your First Case checks for [TRUEMAR] < 0.10 and there are no records that satisfy the condition.

The 2nd case checks [TRUEMAR] > 0.10 **AND** BRANMAR < 0.10. So Even if There are records that Satisfy [TRUEMAR] > 0.10 they won't pass the 2nd condition on BRANMAR

That's why Both your conditions are Failing and you are getting the default value

[image]

It will give you the Value as PMR if you change the 2nd case like this

```
UPDATE @TAB                     
SET Comment = CASE                          
                 WHEN ISNULL([TRUEMAR],0.00) < 0.10 THEN 'UR'                        
                 WHEN ISNULL([TRUEMAR],0.00) > 0.10 OR BRANMAR < 0.10 THEN 'PMR'
                 ELSE 'NA'
              END
```

But Since that's not your requirement, The result you are getting is correct. Please make sure your input values are correct